# Extend Swap partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, swap, ram

I have a system with 125G ram available and a swap partition with 4G, which is constantly full. On a disk with 223 GiB available, I would like to increase the swap partition.
Is it safe to just `swapoff /dev/sda2`, extend the partition table for `/dev/sda2` and resize the swap file system and turn it back on again?

This here is the partition layout of the disk.

> sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot
>
> sda2   8:2    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have enough RAM free to absorb the 4GB then it is safe to just swapoff and resize if that's what you want.

You can of course also add a second partition and add that too, there's unlikely to be any real loss to having two partitions instead of one. Just remember to add it in /etc/fstab

Note that having "too much" swap can lead to situations where your system suddenly requires all that sat back in RAM which will leave processes paused for a long time because even on an NVME, 8GB takes a noticeable amount of time to load.

Obviously though, only you know the specifics of your system.

Comment: So currently I have 55G used from 125G and the machine does mainly virtualization with libvirt. The 225 GiB drive is a 2.5" SSD and should be considerably fast. With that in mind, would you increase the size to 8 GiB and is a problem when swap is constantly full?

Comment: The problem is moving data to and from swap: it takes time. If it just sits there then it might be helping your system a little by increasing capacity for disk cache etc. Personally I'd try extending it, but if you get sudden long pauses then maybe reduce again.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that for quite some time now the difference between the performance of a swap partition compared and a swapfile has been marginal. Adding a swapfile is trivial, doesn't require turning swap off at all and can always be done on the fly.

Comment: Thank you, @tink, for your suggestion. I just added another partition, unmount the boot partition and turning off swap turned out not to be a problem. And creating a new partition with fdisk also went smoothly. I will consider using swapifles when I setup a new machine sometime, but for now it's fine how it is and having a mix between swapfile/swappartition would maybe have confused other admins working on the machine.